# Cannot connect VPN Server On Ubuntu Server 12.04 Using PPTP

Tags: vpn, ubuntu-12.04, pptp

I am trying to replace the old gateway server (running `Fedora core 5`) in my lab with a new one (running `Ubuntu server 12.04`). Three basic functions need to install: NAT, DHCP and VPN. And I got stuck on VPN (using pptp) for a long time and it really made me feel desperate.

I installed `pptpd` and configured the configuration files correctly. When I connected to this new gateway via VPN on `Windows 7`, I always got a `619` error. 
And the following is the related log on the server in `/var/log/syslog`:

```
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer pptpd[3145]: CTRL: Client xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx control connection started
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer pptpd[3145]: CTRL: Starting call (launching pppd, opening GRE)
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer pppd[3146]: pppd 2.4.5 started by root, uid 0
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer pppd[3146]: Using interface ppp0
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer pppd[3146]: Connect: ppp0 <--> /dev/pts/1
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer pptpd[3145]: GRE: read(fd=7,buffer=60f600,len=8260) from network failed: status = -1 error = Protocol not available
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer pptpd[3145]: CTRL: GRE read or PTY write failed (gre,pty)=(7,6)
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer pptpd[3145]: CTRL: Reaping child PPP[3146]
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer pppd[3146]: Hangup (SIGHUP)
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer pppd[3146]: Modem hangup
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer pppd[3146]: Connection terminated.
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer avahi-daemon[733]: Withdrawing workstation service for ppp0.
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer pppd[3146]: Exit.
Mar 23 14:32:53 NATServer pptpd[3145]: CTRL: Client xxx.xxx.xxxxxx control connection finished
```

The xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx is the address of the Windows 7 laptop. The problem seems to be these two lines:

```
GRE: read(fd=7,buffer=60f600,len=8260) from network failed: status = -1 error = Protocol not available
CTRL: GRE read or PTY write failed (gre,pty)=(7,6)
```

I have been looking around and got solutions like below, but all didn't work.

1. `iptables -A INPUT -p 47 -j ACCEPT`
2. set the router to support GRE

I am sure that the problem is on the new gateway server, because the old gateway is still in use and I can connect to it via VPN.

Your help are very much appreciated!

EDIT: Fedora and MAC clients can connect to the VPN server, while the Windows 7 still cannot!

Answer (score 0):

Finally I got to answer my own question, but the answer may not please the audience. One of my colleagues tried connecting to the new gateway using windows 7 via VPN and he succeeded, without changing any configuration on the new gateway. Then I tried on my own laptop, the VPN connected successfully established this time. I don't why.